# WordPress Multisite platform for different city for single db

Tags: multisite, customization, database

I have One WordPress Multisite installation.

myplatform.com (Main platform)

have custom post list for different city say city1, city2 & city3.

Now What I want is on
city1.myplatform.com (city1 platform)

display post/data only related city1 home page for the same theme and db without adding separate data entry for city1.myplatform.com.

Wants to do same for city2.myplatform.com & city3.myplatform.com

Is it possible with MU, WP MU is my idea to solve this you can suggest me other way also.

Comment: What do you mean, `city2` and `city3` are **mirrors** of `city1`?

Comment: @brasofilo No all are different platform for top domain

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to display post specific to the site they were created on, and not on the others, Wordpress MU does this out of the box. There are multiple tables in the same database setup for each site's posts. They all share the same user table, but data for each site is logically separated and then visually displayed separate.